# How to increment number from previous number in PHP

Tags: php

I want to generate a "number in sequence" in PHP on page refresh. Like
if I start with "1" then after page refresh, it should be "2". Please help.

Comment: Store that number in session. At page refresh increment the value

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: Can You Please Give Me An Example????

Comment: `$_SESSION['number'] = isset($_SESSION['number']) ? $_SESSION['number'] + 1 : 1;`

Comment: i Have Random Number Script its generating Number Randomly

Comment: please give proper information in question

Comment: <b>Isetty Ravitejakumar</b>

I want To generate registration number But In Sequence basis like if the i start with 001 then nxt number should be 002 then 003 and so on.....

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using PHP [SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)
`$_SESSION['number']++` will do the trick

**PHP**

```
<?php
     session_start();
     if (!isset($_SESSION['number'])) {
        $_SESSION['number'] = 0;
     }
     $_SESSION['number']++;
?>
```